# Accessing Sobject using javascript

Tags: javascript, sobject

I want to access a Sobject field using javascript in a visual force page and based on its value perform an action.
How can I access a Sobject field using javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What sort of access do you need? You could use javascript remoting, but then if you're already working on a page that has the record loaded in the controller during construction/init you can just use regular old merge fields:

**Controller**

```
public class with sharing SomeController()
{
  public Account a {get; set;

  public SomeController()
  {
    a = [select Id, Name, Rating from Account limit 1];
  }
}
```

**Page**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var accountName = '{!a.Name}';
  var accountRating = '{!a.Rating}'

  if(accountRating == 'Hot')
    alert('HOT ACCOUNT!');

</script>
```

If you need the script to be a bit more dynamic (and not just setup when the page is rendered) then remoting is probably your best bet, but it's hard to suggest the best solution without more information.

Comment: can we access reference columns in java scripts like company__r.name?

Comment: That should still work with the variable assignment, though if you look at remoting it's pretty easy to get a javascript version of an SObject too.